# The no. of factor of $2^{15} \cdot 3^{10} \cdot 5^6$ which are either perfect squares or perfect cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The no of factors of $2^{15} \cdot 3^{10} \cdot 5^6$ which are either perfect squares or perfect cubes

Comment: Please share your thoughts.  Have you considered simpler variations such as counting the number of factors which are perfect squares alone?

Comment: I think in this context the term "divisor" should be used; in that factorisation all _factors_ are $2$, $3$, or $5$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The possible combinations of the exponents are

$$(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14)X(0,2,4,6,8,10)X(0,2,4,6)$$

$$+(0,3,6,9,12,15)X(0,3,6,9)X(0,3,6)$$

$$-(0,6,12)X(0,6)X(0,6)$$

i.e., the result should be $$\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{15}2\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{10}2\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac62\right\rfloor+1\right)$$

$$+\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{15}3\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{10}3\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac63\right\rfloor+1\right)$$

$$-\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{15}6\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{10}6\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac66\right\rfloor+1\right)$$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html

Answer (score 1):

Number of factors which are squares $=8.6.4=192$
Number of factors which are cubes $=6.4.3=72$
Number of factors which are 6th powers $=3.2.2=12$
therefore required answer $=192+72-12=252$